# How to get rid of the grey bar in safari?

Tags: macos, safari

How do I get rid of this (see below) grey bar in safari? Its getting very annoying.[image]

Bigger view:
[image]

I am using safari 7.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to View → Hide Status Bar or press ⌘/

Comment: Thanks. But what does the status bar do anyway?

Comment: @J_W When you hover links, it shows the destination of the link. JavaScript can also do some things with it.

Comment: @J_W Java applets can set the status bar text as well.